# Auto close windows that pop up?

Tags: window-manager

I have some apps that keep popping up ad windows. I want to find a way to automatically close certain app windows as soon as they appear. On Windows, I normally make a simple app in AutoIt and run it. What are my options on OS X?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Which applications are involved here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could save a script like this as a stay open application in AppleScript Editor:

```
on idle
    tell application "TextEdit" to close windows where name contains "Untitled"
    return 1
end idle
```

You can open it at login by adding it to login items. `return 1` waits one second before running the idle handler again. `killall applet` terminates the process.

Closing windows with System Events:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Preview"
    repeat with w in (get windows where title contains "pdf")
        click (button 1 of w where description is "close button")
    end repeat
end tell
```

I use this function to connect to a 3G network:

`mlk() { pkill -x EasyConnect; open -ga Mobiililaajakaista && sleep 30 && pkill -x EasyConnect && osascript -e 'tell application "Safari" to close (tabs of windows where URL is "http://www.elisa.net/slmobi/")' & disown $!; }`

`open -g` opens the application on the background. Without `disown` the shell shows a message like `[1]+  Done` after the background job finishes. `pkill -x` is like `killall` but it doesn't show an error message if it doesn't match any processes.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look up [AutoIt alternatives on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3485254/equivalent-of-autoit-for-mac-os-x).

If you're not bound to an App per se, you might also wanna take a look at Apple Script and take away a built-in language you might actually use even in an other Context.